# How do I redefine what is in a Character Pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following problem:

I have a string in a character pointer variable and would like to shift every character in the string by 1 (for example) and then at the end I would like to store the new string into the original variable.

my code is as follows:

```
int main(){
    char *string = "Hello";

    while (*string != '\0') {
        putchar(*string + 1);
        string++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I use `putchar` it works as expected but when I try this:

`*string = *string +1;` 
I get a segmentation fault

I have also tried these approaches:

`*string = &string +1;`

```
*shifted = *string +1;
shifted = *string;
```

`string = *string +1;`

and none seemed to work, either I got a warning or a segmentation fault.

Is there a way I could redefine the `*string` to have the new shifted letters in it such that I can use it later.

Thank you for the help, greatly appreciated.

Comment: `string` is pointing to a string literal, which is read-only. You can't modify it.

Comment: `char string_array[] = "Hello"; char *string = string_array;` Will make it modifiable.

Comment: some programmers use `const char *text = "foobar";` to protect themselves by asking the compiler to warn them if they try to change the 'read-only' string literal.

Comment: What do you expect the output to be if you start with `Hello` in `string`?

Comment: the expected output should be 'Ifmmp'

Comment: The string is not "in" the pointer.  The string is in memory somewhere and the pointer advises where abouts in memory the string is .

Comment: Trial and error is not a good way to learn C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can't modify `string`. That's why it works with `putchar` but not when you try to modify it. Here's one way to do what you want to do.

```
int main(){
    char *string = "Hello";
    char *shifted = malloc(strlen(string));

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        shifted[i] = string[i] + 1;
    }

    printf("%s %s\n", string, shifted);

    free(shifted);
    return 0;
}
```